# How to auto populate city and state on checkout page while entered the pincode in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout

**Hello Folks,
I am new in Magento 2, I am adding some custum code for changes on checkout page to auto populate the city and state while entered the pincode.**

Can you help me which js file should I change to override the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this, here is one approach:

1. Create your own module with the skeleton files
2. Include your own javascript by appending to checkout_index_index.xml
3. Listen to changes on the postcode fields and fetch your information when it changes.

Detailed steps:

**1. Skeleton files**

app/code/StackExchange/Postcode/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_Postcode" setup_version="0.1.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/Postcode/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_Postcode',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2. Include javascript using checkout_index_index.xml**

app/code/StackExchange/Postcode/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="delivery-option-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">zip-code-listener</item>
                                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="delivery-option" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">StackExchange_Postcode/js/postcode-listener</item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**3. Create the javascript file with your code for fetching**

app/code/StackExchange/Postcode/view/frontend/web/js/postcode-listener.js

```
define([
        "uiComponent",
        'jquery'
    ],
    function(
        Component,
        $
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();

                var self = this;
                $(document).on('change', "[name='postcode']", function () {
                    var postcode = this.value;

                    // your code here
                    alert("The postcode has been changed to: " + postcode);
                    $("[name='city']").val("Some City");
                    // fetch city and region and set using javascript

                });
            },
        });
    }
);
```

Good luck!

Comment: ** Hello @Kristoffer, **

thanks for the code, but I want to do this using knockout js.
Like observe the value and hit the ajax from knockout.

Comment: from above I able to render data but how to bind the data, it gives error while trying to submit.(city and sstat field is required)